# Вставка php в html

Tags: php, html

Ребят, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Хочу сделать так, чтобы определённый контент был доступен только зарегистрированным пользователям.

У меня в правом верхнем углу 2 картинки, одна - "вход", другая - регистрация. Теперь хочу сделать так, чтобы когда человек зарегистрировался, у него убирались эти картинки и писалось "Здравствуйте (и ник того человека)". Вот код:

html:

```
 <div class="block3"> <?php
 include_once("bd.php");
 if(empty($login) and
 empty($password)){ echo '<a
 href="vhod/vhod.html" class="go"> </a>
 <a href="registasia/regis.html"
 class="reg"> </a>'; } else{ echo
 "Привет, ".$login.""; } ?> </div>
```

bd.php

```
 <?php
         $db = mysql_connect ("хост","логин","мой пароль");
         mysql_select_db ("izikatka_users",$db);
        session_start();        $login =
 $_SESSION['login'];
         $password = $_SESSION['password'];
         $id_user = $_SESSION['id'];

        ?>
```

В итоге после всего этого он мне выдаёт:

```
  '; } else{ echo "Привет, ".$login."";
 } ?>
```

Comment: Код из db.php весь? Не понимаю, что он должен возвращать. И, как минимум, тут нет поиска пользователя в базе.

Comment: Да, эта весь код bd.php.
________

Вот поэтому я и прошу помощи, так как не знаю, как это сделать.
________

Есть ещё login.php с формой входа в отдельном файле html.

Comment: @Sambl зачем подключать БД и выбирать базу пользователей, если это не страница входа и запросы к БД не выполняются? Как я понял, если пользователь вошел, то для него прописывается сессия

Comment: Убрал запрос к базе данных, ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, вошедшие пользователи определяются через сессии, поэтому смысла подключать bd.php никакого нет, хватит одного файла. Причин проверять `$_SESSION['password']` и `$_SESSION['id']` не вижу. Вот этот код будет показывать всем гостям ссылки, а вошедшим - их логин:

```
<div class="block3"> 
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])):?> 
<a href="vhod/vhod.html" class="go"> </a> <a href="registasia/regis.html" class="reg"></a>
<?php else:?>
Привет, <?=$_SESSION['login']?>
<?php endif;?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Если у вас PHP версии ниже 5.4, конструкцию <?= нужно заменить на <?php echo

Comment: Сделал всё так, как вы сказали, теперь когда я логинюсь под ником test на сайте, то на главной странице всё равно осталась картинка регестрации, и не пишет Привет, test.

P.S. "Привет," пришлось внести в `<?php echo " Привет,$_SESSION['login']"?>`, так как он отображал "Привет," постоянно.

Comment: Уверены, что правильно скопировали мой код?  Дело в том, что он отображает либо одно, либо другое. Вариант "привет отображался постоянно" исключен.

Comment: Скопировал несколько раз, это точно тот же код, картинки входа и регестрации, отображаются постоянно, "Привет," отображается постоянно, может, проблема в версиях php?
______

Исправил ошибку с БД, он просто не отправлял cooky, перекодировал всё в utf-8 (БЕЗ ВОМ), ошибка исчезла, но всё равно весь контент показывается постоянно, проблема не решена, при авторизации ничего не меняется.
_______

Иногда ощущение, что авторизация не проходит, он просто обновляет страницу, и ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();        
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$id_user = $_SESSION['id'];
```

А в сессию вы эти значения, я так понял, перед присвоением не записали, верно?
Так как `$_SESSION` - это массив, вероятней всего, и не срабатывает ваше условие проверки. А еще после успешного прохождения регистрации лучше использовать:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: Будут вопросы, обращайтесь=)